# How can I convert flv file to a mp3 file by using php?

Tags: php, mp3, flv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert a FLV file recorded with Red5 / FMS to MP3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67647/how-to-convert-a-flv-file-recorded-with-red5-fms-to-mp3)

How can I convert flv file to a mp3 file by using php?

Comment: Ok i accepted some of my controversial questions :( .

Comment: I know it's hard sometimes :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using ffmpeg to do the actual conversion.

So you could use the system() function to call an ffmpeg command such as:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -acodec copy output.mp3
```

Alternatively, this might help: http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/3747.html

Comment: Does it take long to convert 5 minute low quality flv file to mp3 file ?

Comment: The above FFmpeg command will only work if the sound in the .flv file is encoded using mp3. If the sound is of type Speex or Nellymoser then you'll have to drop the `-acodec copy ` part: `ffmpeg -i input.flv output.mp3` From: [Converting .flv to .mp3 server side with FFmpeg](http://audior.ec/blog/converting-flv-to-mp3-server-side-with-ffmpeg/)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in plain php. At least I don't know of any library that would support this transformation. What you can do is call ffmpeg using system() or exec() and execute the desired tranformation (requires ffmpeg to be installed on the host system).

Best wishes,
Fabian